# How do I change the Windows Phone reserved space and other content?

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone, zune-software

I have bought a Windows Phone and I love it.  It reserves some space for other content. When I saw it the first time. It was just a few hundred MB. And it was for documents and other stuffs. Now it's  2.15 GB.

I have searched online forums which said that I might have synced with another computer. But I have never connected my phone any other computer other than my laptop.

How do I fix this from Zune? Or should I do something in my phone?

[image]

Comment: Look in the Zune Settings, there is a slider for that somewhere.

Comment: Yes, this is possible from the Zune Software.

Comment: @TomWijsman Yep.. i tried that.. its just freeing up few hundred MB and reserved space is like 1.8GB...

Comment: @JeyanthKumar: Are you perhaps using a lot of applications, or applications that use a lot of data?

Comment: No.. I found out this one second day after using my phone...

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot below shows it from a Zune 80 standpoint, but you should be able to do the same thing for your Windows Phone:

[image]

To get to this screen - just click `Settings` -> `Device` -> `Reserved Space`.  Just adjust the slider as desired.

Your device **must** be linked to your Windows Live ID *first*, if it isn't already...

Comment: i did that already bro.. its just freeing up just 100 or 200 mb of space...

Comment: @JeyanthKumar that other reserved space is stuff from other computers...If you want to get rid of that, and control it more completely, you'll have to wipe your phone and start over.  The stuff in the 'reserved' part, you see, the software just sees part of it as belonging to other PCs.

Comment: but i never connected it to other pc's other than my laptop.